# jmeter xpath locate element through text and parent

Tags: xpath, jmeter

I get a xml and want to extract the value of one element by XPath Extractor, however it returns "Assertion failure message: -1" in jmeter.

```
<flag>
    <sample>123</sample>
    <others>...</others>
    <target>a test sample</target>
</flag>
<flag>
    <sample>1234</sample>
    <others>...</others>
    <target>a test sample</target>
</flag>
```

In order to get the text of element `<target>` where the `<sample>` is 123, several ways have been tried but failed:

- `//flag[sample='123']/target`
- `//sample[.='123']/../target`
- `//sample[@value='123']/../target/@value`
- `//sample[text()='123']/../target/text()`

Is there a way to capture the value of element `<target>`?

Comment: 1st one is the correct XPath in your scenario...

Comment: Probably a typo in your example but `<others>...<others>` should be `<others>...</others>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, I don't know why all the solution failed; instead, a Regular Expression Extractor works. Maybe XPath Extractor just can't handle those kind of cases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure of the action you want to do, it is a big difference between getting the text and getting the element.

For finding the element you have at least 3 options:

1. find the **target** from **flag** that has a **sample** child with 123 text
   `//flag[./sample[textt()='123']]/target`
2. find the **sample** that has 123 text, go to parent and find **target**
   `//sample[textt()='123']/../target`
3. find the **sample** with that has text 123 and get the **target** sibling
   `this you need to discover yourself`

Now you have the object element that you can use.
If you want the text then you need to add `/text()`

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like:

```
//sample[text()='123']/parent::*/target/text()='a test sample'
```

Demo (assumes [XPath Tester mode of the](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener):

[image]

References:

- [XPath Axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)
- [XPath Language Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/)